# How to detect 4 fingers touches on iOS without exit the app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, touch

I am creating a web-app for iPad where I need to detect when 4 fingers touch my div.page.
I can easily do this with:

```
$('.page').on("touchstart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    touchesNbr = e.originalEvent.touches.length;
}
```

But my problem is that, even if there is a `e.preventDefault()`, iOS automatically show the *"Which app would you like to kill"* screen, when 4 fingers touch the screen and move slightly up.
Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems impossible. 
Multitasking gestures are at the OS level, which means javascript can't access them.

Comment: can we subclass UIWebview , override its touchesBegan Method and check touches.count>3 and use few UIScrollView's methods to do some stuff ?